# How to remove all the transformableNodes already placed in the scene in ARCore?

Tags: android, arcore

I need to delete all the nodes from the scene after I place them, I added this Code to place transformableNodes in the scene

```
val anchorNode = AnchorNode(anchor)
    val transformableNode = TransformableNode(arFragment.transformationSystem)
    transformableNode.setParent(anchorNode)
    transformableNode.renderable = viewRenderable
    arFragment.arSceneView.scene.addChild(anchorNode)
    transformableNode.select()
```

After placing the AnchorNodes I want to remove all the transformableNodes from the scene

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer after many tries

```
for (node in nodesList){
        node.isEnabled = false
        arFragment.arSceneView.scene.removeChild(node)
    }
```